# Flask API endpoint is not accessible from docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, flask, docker-compose

I have simple flask app which uses SQLLite database.

Here is my `app.py` code

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_jwt import JWT
from datetime import timedelta

from db import db
from security import authenticate, identity
from resources.user import UserRegister
from resources.product import Product, ProductList


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///data.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.secret_key = '@hsgvTyb@3gd###123'
api = Api(app)


@app.before_first_request
def create_tables():
  db.create_all()


jwt = JWT(app, authenticate, identity)  # /auth
app.config['JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA'] = timedelta(seconds=1800)

api.add_resource(Product, '/product/<string:name>')
api.add_resource(ProductList, '/products')
api.add_resource(UserRegister, '/register')


if __name__ == '__main__':
  db.init_app(app)
  app.run(port=5000, debug=False)
```

DockerFile as below:

```
FROM python:3
ADD app/ /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD python app.py
```

docker-compose.yml as below:

```
version: "2"
services:
  app:
    container_name: test-146957-app
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: deployments/app/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

Now when I execute `docker-compose up` command it is showing container is running but I hit any endpoints from postman, it does not return any response.

[image]

Comment: Did you expose the port in docker compose?

Comment: @DavidYue Yes. `ports:
      - "5000:5000"` Please see above docker-compose code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add host=0.0.0.0 as Flask run parameter. See the documentation for details: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.run